# Does using Google Analytics include the Measurement Protocol, SDK and User ID (privacy policy)?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

I read at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy that I have to have certain rights to use the Measurement Protocol, SDK and User ID. 
I have an app (for iOS and for Android) and a blog (http://www.mimhr.com/).
I have a privacy policy for the app (not for the blog).
In the policy it is written that the app uses Google Analytics (Google Inc.).
Does it include using the Measurement Protocol, SDK and User ID?
Do I need the policy for my blog in order to use the Measurement Protocol, SDK and User ID?
Thank You in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You are asking a non-programming question on a site that is dedicated to answering programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the laws in your country I guess. Generally you should always inform your users what you do with the data and what tools and what companies are involved. However this is not the right platform for legal advice.